# Mixed up words puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay

When each word is rearranged, one of them can be used to suffix all the others, giving 7 longer words. What are the longer words?

Art, Fire, Oats, Rag, Repel, Rub, Shin, Up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one used as a suffix is

> SHIN anagrammed to NISH.

The longer words are

> TARNISH, REFINISH, ASTONISH, GARNISH, REPLENISH, BURNISH, PUNISH.